# Dockerfile - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement serverlessrepo==0.1.5

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

Below is the Dockerfile for aws sam:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stable
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.4


# Update and allow for apt over HTTPS
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

# download and build Python 3.7, install basic Python libraries
# (this predates pipenv so a mixture of dependencies)
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN cd /usr/src && \
  wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
  tar xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
  cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
  ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
  make altinstall && \
  apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
  pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user && \
    pip3 install --user aws-sam-cli
```

---

that gave error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement serverlessrepo==0.1.5 (from aws-sam-cli) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for serverlessrepo==0.1.5 (from aws-sam-cli)

The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user &&     pip3 install --user aws-sam-cli' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

---

How to install serverlessrepo version 0.1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAM CLI [supports](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/setup.py#L49) Python2.7, 3.6, and 3.7 and your docker image come with python3.5. 
The workaround can be something below or update the base version from your base docker image.

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stable

# Update and allow for apt over HTTPS
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

# Install python3
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user 
RUN python --version
RUN apt-get install python-pip  -y
RUN python2.7 -m pip install aws-sam-cli
```

**Update:**
The base image changed to `buildpack-deps:buster`

```
FROM buildpack-deps:buster
# Update and allow for apt over HTTPS
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt update -y 
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade --ignore-installed six
RUN python3.7 -m pip install aws-sam-cli
RUN  rm /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python
```

[image]

Comment: Am looking for python 3.7 dependency. you are using python2.7 to install aws-sam-cli

Comment: I do not want python2 in my image

Comment: it seems hard to update python in docker image, there is no repository by default to install, and adding repo is having issue. you can try this image `docker pull praekeltfoundation/alpine-buildpack-deps` its light wright base on alpine and having python3.6 which supported in case

Comment: you can change base image, if needed

Comment: I do not find `praekeltfoundation/alpine-buildpack-deps` with python 3.6. I see it is 3.8

Comment: yes you can check user `RUN whoami` you can add user as in normal linux we do

Comment: I would request you to use alpine image or some other base image... because the size of image is going more than 1GB... did you check that?

Comment: yes alpine is much better, I will look into later today

Comment: I already looked into it... here is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57229496/3317808

Comment: okay so then this answer should be considered accepted, So I will follow up you that question

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001628/public-key-is-not-available-no-pubkey-f76221572c52609d   and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000876/docker-file-master-jenkins-hudson-util-hudsonfailedtoload

Answer (score 1):

It will not work with python3. Check [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/922) out.

You need to install either [Python2.7, 3.6, or 3.7](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/setup.py#L49).

More info [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/922#issuecomment-452350773).

Hope this helps.