# pip install of aws-sam-cli package with python3.7 version

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, aws-sam-cli

In the below docker file:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV HOME /home/samcli
ENV PATH $HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir /root/bin /aws; \
    apk add --no-cache groff less bash python jq curl py-pip tzdata

RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python2-dev python3-dev linux-headers musl-dev && \
    pip install --upgrade pip; \
    adduser samcli -Du 5566; \
    chown -R samcli $HOME;

USER samcli

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;

USER root

RUN apk del .build-deps; \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

---

Layer(`RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;`) is installing with python 2.7, despite image has python3.7 installed.

I see below deprecation error when installing python package:

`Step 9/11 : RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;`

`DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/`

---

How to install aws package with python3.7?
 because below command is using python2

`pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using python offical image based on alpine so you will do not need to maintain and install the python version. Below base image is base on `alpine 3.9` and `python version is 3.7`

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9

ENV HOME /home/samcli
ENV PATH $HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps python2-dev  python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev && \
    adduser samcli -Du 5566; \
    chown -R samcli $HOME;
RUN apk add --no-cache groff less bash jq curl py-pip tzdata
USER samcli

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;
USER root

RUN apk del .build-deps; \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: Does base image leave root access to rest of the layers?

Comment: yes, as you see the user only changes for `RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;`

Comment: What is an optimal size of an image? so that we keep this in mind, when we add layers layers to an image

Comment: Isn't this python3.9 image?

Comment: Its around 400mb and it's alpine 3.9, pythons 3.7

Comment: You can check version of python docker exec - it name ash - c "python - - version"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242577/error-serverlessrepo-0-1-8-has-requirement-pyyaml-3-12

Comment: Did I answer your comment?

Comment: yes, but this is now another problem ;) but for me, it was working fine. and my answer already have the answer to your this question.

Comment: This image does not work after removing `python2-dev` from the file

Comment: why do you want to remove if this is the part of your question? because there is a dependency of further package on python2-dev

Comment: this is can be a separate question, Community discourages to ask multiple questions in single question! So the answer is correct for `pip install of aws-sam-cli package with python3.7 version`. Good luck :)

Comment: Let me look in this question 

Answer (score 0):

This Dockerfile works for me.

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN apk --no-cache add python3 py3-pip gcc musl-dev python3-dev

RUN pip install aws-sam-cli awscli

...
```