# ERROR: serverlessrepo 0.1.8 has requirement pyyaml~=3.12

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, pyyaml

Below is the docker file with base image python 3.7:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9


ENV HOME /home/someteam
ENV PATH $HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps python2-dev  python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev && \
    addgroup someteam --gid=5566; \
    adduser -G someteam -Du 5566 -h /home/someteam -s /bin/bash someteam; \
    chown -R someteam $HOME;
RUN apk add --no-cache groff less bash jq curl py-pip tzdata
USER someteam

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;
USER root

RUN apk del .build-deps; \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

USER someteam
WORKDIR $HOME

ADD somescript.sh $HOME/somescript.sh
```

---

gives error:

```
ERROR: serverlessrepo 0.1.8 has requirement pyyaml~=3.12, but you'll have pyyaml 5.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: aws-sam-cli 0.18.0 has requirement PyYAML~=3.12, but you'll have pyyaml 5.1 which is incompatible.
```

---

How to install `pyyaml 3.12`? with python 3.6 or python 3.7 base image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `PyYAML==3.12` for your aws-sam-cli
as you Docker image come with `pyyaml 5.1` by default which have compatibility issue with `aws-sam-cli`. All you need to install `pyyaml 3.12` before installation of `aws-sam-cli`

```
RUN pip install PyYAML==3.12
USER someteam
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;
USER root
```

Comment: ENV will just create environment variable

Answer (score 1):

after this pull request is released, serverlessrepo should be on 5.1. According to the PR, SAM CLI will be upgraded to 5.1 soon.

Comment: Can you share the repo name? let me check the PR... which branch is the PR raised?