# public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F76221572C52609D

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, apt-get

For the below docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.1

ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1

# This is FROM openjdk:8-jdk  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
                apt-transport-https \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN echo 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1

# see https://bugs.debian.org/775775
# and https://github.com/docker-library/java/issues/19#issuecomment-70546872
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

# see CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION notes above
RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

##### END OF THE JDK

##### START Jenkins Slave Node Config settings

# Create Jenkins User
RUN useradd jenkins -m -s /bin/bash

RUN chown -R jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins /tmp
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /tmp

# Add the jenkins user to sudoers
RUN echo "jenkins    ALL=(ALL)    ALL" >> etc/sudoers

# Must install docker to create docker images from docker container. Inception. Head... hurts.
# container must be called with -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    docker-engine \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# This must run after the docker install 
RUN gpasswd -a jenkins docker

USER jenkins
```

---

build image is failing for command at line #38

```
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]
```

---

with error:

> W: GPG error: https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-jessie InRelease:
>   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
>   is not available: NO_PUBKEY F76221572C52609D
>
> ```
> W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
> AA8E81B4331F7F50
> W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages
> ```
>
> 404  Not Found
>
> ```
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
>
> ERROR: Service 'slavedotnet' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y   openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"
>   ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"    && rm -rf
> ```
>
> /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]'
>   returned a non-zero code: 100

---

How public key error can get resolved?

Comment: NOTE: This question works Debian, Not Unbuntu or Linux Mint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues here:

> 1) W: GPG error: https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F76221572C52609D
>   W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
>   AA8E81B4331F7F50

**Solution:**

Move the keyserver add actions to the place before `RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list`, meanwhile add `AA8E81B4331F7F50` also as next:

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50
```

> 2) W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

**Solution:**

`microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.1` base on `debian8`, and you want to use `openjdk8` which was default not in apt repository. So you use `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main`.

Unfortunately, if you check http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/, you will find `jessie-backports` had been removed. So you had to switch to archived url like next (Comment the old url, just use the url next):

```
#RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

Meanwhile, you had to add next after doing above to resolve [release-file-expired-problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-work-around-release-file-expired-problem-on-a-local-mirror):

```
RUN echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until \"false\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100disablechecks
```

> 3) ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
>   ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1

**Solution:**

Not sure how you get this version, but in fact after change to archive jessie backports, what you could get is something like next:

```
root@2ecaeffec483:/etc/apt# apt-cache policy openjdk-8-jdk
openjdk-8-jdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1
  Version table:
     8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

So, you had to change to next:

```
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u171
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1
```

Answer (score 4):

##### This script will automatically add *most* missing GPG keys:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

for PUBKEY in $(apt-get update 2>&1 | grep NO_PUBKEY | awk '{print $NF}')
do
 wget -q "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x${PUBKEY}" -O - | sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/p' | apt-key add - 2>/dev/null
done
```

The only prerequisite is to have `wget` installed. It can also be used with `curl`.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the below:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:

AA8E81B4331F7F50
```

Just use the below code:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```