# dockerfile - openjdk-8-jdk have unmet dependencies

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, apt

In continuation to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58001628/3317808), below is the updated docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.1

ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1

# This is FROM openjdk:8-jdk  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
                apt-transport-https \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50

# RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN echo 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list


RUN echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until \"false\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100disablechecks

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

# ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
# ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1
# ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u222
# ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u171
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1

# see https://bugs.debian.org/775775
# and https://github.com/docker-library/java/issues/19#issuecomment-70546872
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

# see CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION notes above
RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

##### END OF THE JDK

##### START Jenkins Slave Node Config settings

# Create Jenkins User
RUN useradd jenkins -m -s /bin/bash

RUN chown -R jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins /tmp
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /tmp

# Add the jenkins user to sudoers
RUN echo "jenkins    ALL=(ALL)    ALL" >> etc/sudoers

# Must install docker to create docker images from docker container. Inception. Head... hurts.
# container must be called with -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    docker-engine \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# This must run after the docker install 
RUN gpasswd -a jenkins docker

USER jenkins
```

---

Below is the error:

```
Step 16/26 : RUN set -x     && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y       openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]
 ---> Running in 6d823a145982
+ apt-get update
Get:1 https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-jessie InRelease [48.7 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
Get:3 https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages [7366 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages [1171 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Get:9 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [892 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 11.5 MB in 14s (803 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
+ apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk=8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1 ca-certificates-java=20140324
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-8-jdk : Depends: openjdk-8-jre (= 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: openjdk-8-jdk-headless (= 8u171-b11-1~bpo8+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: Service 'slavedotnet' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -x    && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y       openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

How to resolve this version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports):

> The backports repository is deactivated by default. So, if you want to install a backported package, you will have to state that explicitly.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> debian:/home/human# aptitude -t buster-backports install cockpit
> ```

So, for your case, you need to change to next:

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports -y \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    ca-certificates-java \
```

Here, I suggest you don't add version selection for package like next:

```
openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"
```

Because, default it will choose the latest version in this os release apt repo. If you insist, then for backports repo, you need to separate install them:

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports -y \
    openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" && \
apt-get install -t jessie-backports -y \
    ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
```