# Building from Dockerfile and getting "The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY"

Tags: docker, debian

I'm trying to build a PHP 5.3/Apache for local use using a Dockerfile that starts:

```
FROM php:5.3-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev
```

But when "Reading package lists" I get:

```
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9D6D8F6BC857C906 NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
```

After reading [this page](https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/) I tried adding this after the first line:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
```

But get this error:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
9D6D8F6BC857C906
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 130.89.148.77 80]
```

Knowing next to nothing about Ubuntu vs Debian I tried the same but with `keyring.debian.org` in place of `keyserver.ubuntu.com` and got:

```
gpgkeys: key AA8E81B4331F7F50 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001628/public-key-is-not-available-no-pubkey-f76221572c52609d) I tried this:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
```

But get the same GPG Error as originally.

I'm now stumped as to how to proceed. (I know PHP 5.3 is *very* out of date but I can't change that unfortunately.)

Answer (score 4):

From http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=141778, one solution is.

```
gpg --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50
gpg --export AA8E81B4331F7F50| apt-key add -
```

The Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM php:5.3-apache

RUN for key in AA8E81B4331F7F50 7638D0442B90D010 9D6D8F6BC857C906; do \
        gpg --recv-keys "$key" \
        && gpg --export "$key" | apt-key add - ; \
    done

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

After several more attempts and errors I found that just doing this, without the preceding install of `apt-transport-https ca-certificates` seems to do the job:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010
```

I do get this error but it doesn't *appear* to affect anything, and installation continues afterwards:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
9D6D8F6BC857C906
```

Comment: Hey @Phill Gyford. Are you still using this image? I'm trying to follow your advice but I get

```#13 27.82 ?: pool.sks-keyservers.net: Host not found
#13 27.82 gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
#13 27.83 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
#13 27.83 gpg: Total number processed: 0```

Answer (score 1):

Having run into the same issues and finding that none of the above solutions worked, I considered the fact that I was calling upon an image that was a slightly older version than current (openjdk:10-sid) and thought that being a dead-end release, there would be no keys to match to for updates.

So, I just commented out:

RUN apt-get update

and let the other apt-get installs happen.  The build finally succeeded.  I wouldn't do this as a rule, but it seems reasonable for older images.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same kind of error with my node docker image, the docker file I used is the following;

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install dumb-init
RUN npm i && npm run build
CMD ["dumb-init", "node", "dist/app.js"]
```

The error is related to the ubuntu, I replaced the base image of the node:lts with the official node image after that being able to build the docker image

```
FROM node:16.16.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install dumb-init
RUN npm i && npm run build
CMD ["dumb-init", "node", "dist/app.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on *`Debian`*/*`Debian(Container)`*, to fix your problem:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
9D6D8F6BC857C906
```

Just try the below code:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```