# When I work with ubuntu 18.04 server on aws, I get this error

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

When I work with ubuntu 18.04 server on aws, I get this error

I tried to delete monog from the server and then install it from the beginning, but it gives me this error

[image]

I've searched google stackoverflow and other places but to no avail

Comment: Your question I think it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001628/public-key-is-not-available-no-pubkey-f76221572c52609d, You can check it. Hope this help

Comment: it didn't work for me